Slower with Python module yt_dlp than command line
I downloaded information from a Youtube playlist with Python. For that I used the following code:
import yt_dlp
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyiJZcChPSpxLQHGf6K5CwGv7QIR55ea6'

def get_video_info(url):
    ydl_opts = {"ignoreerrors": True}
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    return info
info = get_video_info(url)
print()
print(info.get('entries'))

It is much slower with Python (several minutes) than with the command line (a few seconds), and the json downloaded with the command line offers more information. This is the command line command I used:
yt-dlp --flat-playlist --dump-single-json  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyiJZcChPSpxLQHGf6K5CwGv7QIR55ea6 | jq '.'

Is there any command or option in Python to make it faster?
My knowledge of Linux, computer science and programming is basic.
The English is from a machine translation.
I got the information I was looking for but it takes much longer in Python.

I test your code. The reason of slow is there are some invalid URLs in the playlist, which causes yt_dlp have to retry. You can control the retry times by parameter skip_playlist_after_errors.
Please refer code below:
import yt_dlp
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyiJZcChPSpxLQHGf6K5CwGv7QIR55ea6'

def get_video_info(url):
    # Use dump_single_json to output JSON
    # Assign -1 to skip_playlist_after_errors to do not retry 
    ydl_opts = {"ignoreerrors": True, "dump_single_json": True, "skip_playlist_after_errors":-1}
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    return info
info = get_video_info(url)
print()
print(info.get('entries'))


Thanks, I tried the code you posted and it worked fast
